# Как прикрутить MinGW к Sublime Text 2?

Tags: c++, python, sublime-text, mingw

Добрый вечер!

Может ли кто-нибудь поделиться опытом, как прикрутить `mingw` к `Sublime`?

Нашел какой-то конфиг в инете, но при запуске скомпилированной программы выскакивают ошибки с недостающими файлами из папки "../MinGW/bin/".

Вот, собственно, сам конфиг:

```
{
     "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name"],
     "path": "c:\\Program Files\\MinGW\\bin\\"
}
```

Comment: Кое-что заметил...

Если поместить скомпилированный файл в директорию "../MinGW/bin/", то все замечательно запускается и работает. Понимаю, то что решение проблемы кроется перед носом, но сам дойти до самого решения не могу.

Comment: А если прописать в `path` путь к __вашей__ папке с собранным бинарником?

Comment: Это ни к чему не приводит. 
При таком конфиге вылетает ошибка с недостающими файлами. 

     "cmd": ["c:\\Program Files\\MinGW\\bin\\mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name"],
     "path": "c:\\helloworld\\"

При этом вообще ничего не происходит:

     "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name"],
     "path": "c:\\helloworld\\"

Comment: Вы только что статически прилинковали `libgcc` и `libstdc++` к вашему `exe`'шнику. С учетом того, к каким проблемам потенциально может приводить статическая линковка рантаймов, очень сомневаюсь, что это хорошее решение.

Comment: Для моего уровня, я думаю, это пока что не важно. Но все же интересно.. А к каким проблемам это может привести в дальнейшем?

Answer (score 1):

Перенесено из вопроса, автор ответил самостоятельно:

Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос! Мне всего лишь надо было добавить один параметр в cmd. Это параметр `"-static"`.

Итак, вот мой `MinGW.sublime-build`, который прекрасно работает:

```
{
    "path": "c:\\Program Files\\MinGW\\bin\\",
    "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-static", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"]
}
```